# Hour is not showing in 00 format

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
 <a href="#"><span id="live_time">Server Time: <strong><?php echo date('h:i:s A'); ?></strong></span></a>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        // use php to get the server time
                        var serverdate = new Date('<?php echo date('F d, Y h:i:s'); ?>');
                        function refresh_time(){
                            serverdate.setSeconds(serverdate.getSeconds() + 1);
                            var hh=serverdate.getHours();
                            var m=serverdate.getMinutes();
                            var s=serverdate.getSeconds();
                               m=checkTime(m);
                            s=checkTime(s);
                            var dd = " AM";
                            var h = hh;
                            if (h >= 12) {
                                h = hh-12;
                                dd = " PM";
                            }
                            if (h == 0) {
                                h = 12;
                            }


                            var output = h+":"+m+":"+s+""+dd;
                            document.getElementById("live_time").innerHTML = 'Server Time: <strong>'+output+'</strong>';
                        }
                            function checkTime(i) {
                                if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};
                                return i;
                            }

                        window.onload = function(){
                          setInterval("refresh_time()", 1000);
                        }



                    </script>
```

When I access page first time it show me 07:11:14 AM after one second time become 7:11:15 AM  How I can output at every refresh in H format? like 07:11:15 ?

Comment: So you don't want to show AM or PM? Whats your desired output format from existing one?

Comment: @pro_cheats Read my description. I say "How I can output at every refresh in H format? like 07:11:15 ?"

Comment: Can you please reformat your code ? It is almost unreadable.

Comment: @DigitalBeko what about AM or PM?

Comment: OT, but setInterval isn't guaranteed to be exact. You might find that your "server time" doesn't stay in sync very well using this method. it might be better to find the offset between server and local, and then add/subtract that to local time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add the `0` manually:

```js
var date = new Date();
currentHours = date.getHours();
var currentHours2 = 6;
var currentHours3 = 18;
currentHours = ("0" + currentHours).slice(-2);
currentHours2 = ("0" + currentHours2).slice(-2);
currentHours3 = ("0" + currentHours3).slice(-2);
console.log(currentHours)
console.log(currentHours2)
console.log(currentHours3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ES8 `padStart()` to pad the hour with 0.

```js
var h = "5";
console.log(h.padStart(2, "0"));
```

Or if not use the older syntax

```js
var h = "5";
console.log(h.length == 1 ? "0"+h : h);
```